# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token F in JSON at position 1

Tags: javascript, json

Ошибка при нажатии на поиск на главной странице сайта
https://kinfix.ru/

```js
/*
=====================================================
Field Search - Сортировка новостей пользователями по доп полям и не только
-----------------------------------------------------
Автор : Gameer
-----------------------------------------------------
Site : http://gameer.name/
-----------------------------------------------------
Copyright (c) 2016 Gameer
=====================================================
Данный код защищен авторскими правами
*/
var back_url = window.location.pathname;
var back_title = document.title;
var back_speedbar = document.getElementById("dle-speedbar");
$(function(){
 $('body').on('click', '[data-fieldsearch=submit]', function() {
  var $filter_field = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
  window.history.replaceState(null, null, "/");
  ShowLoading("Ищем... ищем... ищем...");
  $.post(dle_root + "engine/ajax/field_search.php", { form_field : $filter_field }, function(data){
   if(data)
   {
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, "/");
    var content = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
    $("#dle-content1").remove();
    $("#dle-content").css("display", "none");
    $("#dle-content").before("<div id=\"dle-content1\">" + content.content + "</div>");
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, content.url);
   }
  });
  HideLoading("");
  return false;
 });
 $('body').on('click', '.field_search_nav > a', function() {
  var $filter_field = $( this ).attr("href");
  window.history.replaceState(null, null, "/");
  ShowLoading("Ищем... ищем... ищем...");
  $.post(dle_root + "engine/ajax/field_search.php", { form_field : $filter_field, filter_nav : 1 }, function(data){
   if(data)
   {
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, "/");
    var content = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
    document.title = content.meta_title;
    $("#dle-speedbar").html(content.speedbar);
    $("#dle-content1").remove();
    $("#dle-content").css("display", "none");
    $("#dle-content").before("<div id=\"dle-content1\">" + content.content + "</div>");
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, content.url);
   }
  });
  HideLoading("");
  return false;
 });
 $( "[data-filtertriger=fieldseacrh]" ).change(function() {
  var $filter_field = $( this ).serialize();
  window.history.replaceState(null, null, "/");
  ShowLoading("Ищем... ищем... ищем...");
  $.post(dle_root + "engine/ajax/field_search.php", { form_field : $filter_field }, function(data){
   if(data)
   {
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, "/");
    var content = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
    $("#dle-content1").remove();
    $("#dle-content").css("display", "none");
    $("#dle-content").before("<div id=\"dle-content1\">" + content.content + "</div>");
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, content.url);
   }
  });
  HideLoading("");
 });
 
 $('body').on('click', '[data-fieldsearch="reset"]', function() {
  window.history.replaceState(null, null, back_url);
  ShowLoading("Секунду...");
  document.title = back_title;
  $("#dle-speedbar").html(back_speedbar);
  $('[data-filtertriger=fieldseacrh] input[type="text"]').each(function(i){
   if($(this).attr('name') != undefined)
   {
    if($(this).attr('name').indexOf('r-') + 1)
    {
     var slider = $(this).data("ionRangeSlider");
     slider.update({
      from: slider.options.min,
      to: slider.options.max
     });
    }
    else
    {
     $(this).val('');
    }
   }
  });
  $('[data-filtertriger=fieldseacrh] select').each(function(i){
   $(this).children('option').each(function(n){
    $(this).attr('selected', false);
   });
  });

  $('[data-filtertriger=fieldseacrh] input[type="radio"], [data-filtertriger=fieldseacrh] input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i){
   $(this).attr('checked', false);
  });
  $("#dle-content1").remove();
  $("#dle-content").css("display", "block");
  HideLoading("");
  return false;
 });
});
```

Comment: ссылка ведет на заглушку

Comment: Включил сайт. Извиняюсь

Answer (score 1):

Если посмотреть что возвращает сервер в ответ на запрос

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно заметить, что это просто текст ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Fatal error: Class 'DLEPlugins' not found in /home/admin/web/kinfix.ru/public_html/engine/classes/templates.class.php on line 24

Следовательно ошибку надо искать на сервере.